# Winforms: Getting Position of Process Before Process is Terminated

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process

I'm using Process.Start("filename.pdf") to launch an AcroRd32 process from my Winforms project.  I set the EnableRaisingEvents property to true on the process and subscribed the Exit event.

After the pdf file is opened, the user may decide to reposition the adobe reader window.  Is there a way I can get the position (x, y, w, h) of the process window just before the process is terminated either programmatically, via the task manager, or by clicking the X button.

The problem I am facing is that by the time the Exit event is fired and I try to retrieve the position of the process using the GetWindowRect() function in the event handler for the Exit event, the process has already been killed and hence, there is no window handle available.

Comment: That is Adobe Reader's job.  It already knows how to do that.  Try it.

Comment: Wow!  Seems like you are right.  Can't believe I spent so much time on this when it is already built into Acrobat reader.  Thanks for pointing that out.